Synchronize a BackgroundWorker
I am using a BackgroundWorker to update controls on a Form every 30sec.  The BackgroundWorker opens a COM port and reads data from a serial instrument.  It asserts ReportProgress() to update controls on the Form.  My Form also contains a toggle switch that opens the same COM port as the BackgroundWorker to change the state of the instrument.  I need to stop the BackgroundWorker from running when the Toggle Switch's StateChanged event fires to avoid a race condition and to limit access to the COM port to one thread.
Here are excerpts from my code:
       private void BackgroundWorkerStatus_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                while (!BackgroundWorkerStatus.CancellationPending)
                {
                    // Get new values (Open COM Port, read state)
                    ReadState();

                    // Update the User Interface
                    BackgroundWorkerStatus.ReportProgress(0);

                    // Wait before updating again
                    Thread.Sleep(UpdateInterval);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show(….)
            }
        }


        private void BackgroundWorkerStatus_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                 // Update controls on the Form
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show(….);
            }


        private void ToggleSwitch_StateChanged(object sender, NationalInstruments.UI.ActionEventArgs e)
        {
                // Open COM Port, set state, update Form
        }


I have tried calling CancelAsync() at the beginning of the StateChanged event and calling RunWorkerAsync() at the end.
I tried creating a global Boolean that is set in the StateChanged event and evaluated in the DoWork method.
Neither of these work presumably because CancelPending and the global Boolean are not evaluated continuously, and their state changes while the BackgroundWorker thread is in the middle of running.
I also tried using a Semaphore, but this causes a cross threading exception when the background thread tries to update the UI.  I understand why but don’t know how to work around it.
Essentially I need a combination of Semaphore and BackgroundWorker to synchronize a background task that can also update the UI.
What is the appropriate way to do this?
Thank you!

With the information given, I would cancel the background worker when the state changes (when the port needs to be accessed from the main thread), then start a new one after the config change.

It gets very simple when you use a Timer instead of a BackgroundWorker.

Hans, thanks for your response but I don't understand what you are suggesting.  I already tried to cancel the background worker but it doesn't work.  I believe it doesn't work because CancelAsync() doesn't actually stop the BackgroundWorker task from running.  It asserts CancelPending, which is only evaluated at specific times.  If CancelPending is asserted in the middle of the worker thread, it won't be evaluated until the next time it is run.  This summarizes the race condition.

I don't understand how a timer would solve the issue.  If the timer fires the event that opens the COM port to read the state at the same time that the user clicks the toggle switch on the form, an exception occurs because the COM port is already in use.  Can you please explain how this would work?

The fact you have a "sleep", implies a "timer" based solution. A Dispatcher Timer fires on the UI thread; no problem updating the UI if the timer fires every 30 sec. You can create your own "cancel" token ... Just set a flag that the BGW accesses at the top of the timer tick that says: "Skip for now" .... No "canceling" required. (Stop skipping ... or do a "restart" sequence when necessary). BGW can set it's own flag to indicate it is now "skipping". You're now syncronized.

The code in ToggleSwitch_StateChanged should wait on the backgroundworker to finish in cancelled state. You can subscribe to the completet event and set a flag when cancelled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted?view=net-8.0#system-componentmodel-backgroundworker-runworkercompleted
